# ListView сложение суммы чисел в строках

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

помогите пожалуйста с кодом. Каким образом можно сложить числа строк из 3,4,5 столбца и передать его в Столбец "Всего".

**Код записи данных в listView1**

```
       //Создайте считыватель данных и выполняем команду
            dataReader = await cmd1.ExecuteReaderAsync();
            //Прочитайте данные и сохраните их в списке
            if (dataReader.FieldCount > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataReader.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        if (i == 0)
                        {
                            listView1.Columns.Add(dataReader.GetName(0), 0, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            listView1.Columns.Add(dataReader.GetName(i).ToString().Replace("_", " "), 80, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
                        }
                    }

                    ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem();
                    //
                    while (await dataReader.ReadAsync())
                    {
                        lv = listView1.Items.Add(dataReader[dataReader.GetName(0)].ToString().Replace('_', ' '));
                        for (int h = 1; h < dataReader.FieldCount; h++)
                        {

                            lv.SubItems.Add(dataReader[dataReader.GetName(h)].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 1; i < listView1.Columns.Count; i++)
                    listView1.Columns[i].Width = -2;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `public int Total => Column1 + Column2 + Column3;`

Comment: Когда создаете колонки в этом listview, при этом запомните, где именно расположен этот "Всего".

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Вообще без понятия как это сделать

Comment: Вы явно используете не тот компонент для своих нужд. ListView не предназначен для отображения табличных данных с вычислениями. Возьмите DataGridView.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov как мне это облегчит

Comment: И вообще, логика не должна зависеть от графических компонентов. Вся логика должна быть завязана на модели данных (DataTable или какая-нибудь типизированная коллекция типа List<T>).

Comment: @Alexander Petrov ну вот как выше написал это возможно сделать в listview. DataGridView - мне не подходит для моих задач

Comment: Это цикл по поиску нужных колонок сложения   int tt;
               tt=listView1.Columns.Count - 6;
                for (int i = 3; i < tt; i++)
                {

                }

Comment: ListView предназначен для отображения данных, и не более того. Как правильно сказал Alexander Petrov, сделайте метод для вычисляемого поля в модели данных.

Comment: @Макс Жуков можно просто заполнить эту колонку циклом, зачем что то придумывать лишнего, я просто не знаю как сложить строку первую и передать его в колонку "всего". Вот это мне нежно

Comment: @Alexander Petrov поправил

Comment: У вас есть такая строка кода: `listView1.Columns[i].Width`. Неужели сложно вот также пройтись в цикле по колонкам и найти нужную используя свойство `Name`?

Comment: listView1.Items [i].SubItems ["Всего"] я то нашел

Comment: @Alexander Petrov читай вопрос по внимательней )

Comment: Жаль нельзя несколько минусов ставить... "Угадал все буквы, не смог назвать слово". "Нашел нужную колонку, не смогу вставить в нее значение".

Comment: @Alexander Petrov ну вот я не знаю что поделать